# Retrofit 2 формат json

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Доброго времени.
Имею формат json с сервера:

```js
{
  "type" : "type",
  "username" : "username",
  "password" : "password"
}
```

Собственно  этот же формат уходит  на сервер.

Retrofit  выдает  исключение:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was
>   BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $  Body

Если я правильно понял,  проблема  с  форматом. Но как  решить не понимаю.
Буду  рад помощи.

Answer (score 1):

нашел  ошибку.

```
RetrofitApp.getApi().getToken(mLoginDataModelJSon).enqueue(new Callback<List<TokenModelJSon>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<TokenModelJSon>> call, Response<TokenModelJSon> response) {
            System.out.println(response.body().getAccessToken() + "  Body");
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                response.body().getAccessToken();
                System.out.println(response.body().getAccessToken());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<TokenModelJSon>> call, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println(t + "  Body");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "An error occurred during networking", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Нужно  было вместо Call> вставить Call  то есть  без List. И  все  затикало  как  часики)